# Replace string before a string?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Sorry, I'm bad English. I'm going to post my code now:

```
    $image = 'http://example.com/thisisimage.gif';
    $filename = substr($image, strrpos($image, '/') + 1);
    echo '<br>';
    echo $filename;
    echo '<br>';            
    echo preg_replace('/^[^\/]+/', 'http://mydomain.com', $image);   
    echo '<br>';
```

$image is string;

$filename is image name (in example above, it returns 'thisisimage.gif')

Now i want replace all before $filename with 'http://mydomain.com', my code is above but it doesnt work.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to turn //example.com/thisisimage.gif to //localhost/thisisimage.gif ? Really I did not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Ihsan: yes! i have edited, is 'http://mydomain.com'.

Comment: Then you have allready done the hard part. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$foo = explode($filename, $image);
echo $foo[0];
```

Explode "splits" one the given paramater ( in your case $filename ). It returns an array with  where the keys are split on the string you gave.

And if you just want to change the url. you use a str_replace

```
   $foo = str_replace("http://example.com", "http://localhost", $image);

   //This will change "http://example.com" to "http://localhost", like a text replace in notepad.
```

In your case:

```
    $image = 'http://example.com/thisisimage.gif';
    $filename = substr($image, strrpos($image, '/') + 1);
    $foo = explode($filename, $image);
    echo '<br>';
    echo $filename;
    echo '<br>';            
    echo str_replace($foo[0], "http://yourdomain.com/", $url);
    echo '<br>';
```

Comment: i think this is the best solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's another approach in which you don't need a regular expression:

in Short:

```
$image = 'http://example.com/thisisimage.gif';
$url = "http://mydomain.com/".basename($image);
```

---

Explanation:

If you just want the file name without url's or directory path's, `basename()` is your friend;

```
$image = 'http://example.com/thisisimage.gif';
$filename = basename($image);
```

output: thisisimage.gif

Then you can add whatever domain you want:

```
$mydomain = "http://mydomain.com/";
$url = $mydomain.$filename;
```

Comment: dont forget the "/" basename() just grabs the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$image = 'http://example.com/thisisimage.gif';  
echo preg_replace('/^http:\/\/.*\.com/', 'http://mydomain.com',$image);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other people here have given good answers about how to do it - regex has its advantages but also drawbacks - its slower, respectively requires more resources and for something simple as this, I would advice you to use the explode approach, but while speaking for regex functions you also may try this, instead your preg_replace:

```
echo preg_replace('#(?:.*?)/([^/]+)$#i', 'http://localhost/$1', $image);
```

It seems variable length positve lookbehind is not supported in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This should simply work:

```
$image = 'http://example.com/thisisimage.gif';
$filename = substr($image, strrpos($image, '/') + 1);
echo '<br>';
echo $filename;
echo '<br>';            
echo 'http://mydomain.com/'.$filename;   
echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just like to add your own domain before the file name, try this:

```
$filename = array_pop(explode("/", $image));
echo "http://mydomain.com/" . $filename;
```

if you wanna only replace thedomain, try this:

```
echo preg_replace('/.*?[^\/]\/(?!\/)/', 'http://mydomain.com/', $image);
```